# Modifying web pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am a wp beginner and I'm trying to modify webpages for use on my website.  I have created a child theme and it appears in my wp dashboard.  I have uploaded the images I wish to use via ftp onto my server.  I have modified the coding on several of my child theme pages to include my images but nothing is showing up.

This code is from my custom-header.php page-

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();
    if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
            **<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/Legion-Scotland.jpg">?>" alt="Legion-Logo" />**
        </a>
<?php } // if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) ?>
```

Any help would be MOST appreciated as this is for an overdue college project.

Thanks

Comment: are you getting any console errors in your browser?

Comment: use `<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/Legion-Scotland.jpg" alt="Legion-Logo" />`

Comment: I don't think so??? None of the modifications I have made have changed any of my pages.  I assumed that I needed to modify the php code??

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/Legion-Scotland.jpg">?>" alt="Legion-Logo" />
```

Replace it as

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/Legion-Scotland.jpg" alt="Legion-Logo" />
```

Comment: Still not managed to change my header image.  Could I possibly use this code instead?

Comment: function header_image() {
    $image = get_header_image();
    if ( $image ) {
        echo esc_url( $image );
    }
}